# (How) can I export the call stack when on a breakpoint?

Tags: delphi, ide, delphi-xe2, breakpoints, callstack

Is there a way to export the call stack when the code is stopped on a breakpoint?

I have very long ID strings that I need to grab for use in another program (see pic), and retyping from a screen capture is not really an option ;-)

I'm clicking around in the XE2 IDE but can't find anything.

(Workaround: For now I continue stepping through the code after the breakpoint, until I have moved far enough back up the stack that the local variables are available again.)

[image]

Comment: `ToolsAPI.IOTAThread50.CallHeaders` might be useful.

Comment: *I continue stepping through the code after the breakpoint, until I have moved far enough back up the stack that the local variables are available again.* FWIW, you should be able to double click on the procedure and the debugger will switch context to make locals and arguments available for watch/inspection

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The call stack debug window supports the usual selection and clipboard shortcuts. So use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to select the entire call stack, and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to copy to the clipboard. Or you can select a single item and copy with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. Or you can select multiple items with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+click and <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+click, and so on.